# Why is the foreign-key item not connected?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Update: Solved. See comments.

What is wrong with the setup of the models that foreign-key item ('Comment') doesn't seem to be connected?

I am working on the Assessment part of Mozilla's Django tutorials and set up a blog-with four models: Post, Author, Comment, Commenter. While I can create posts and posts with comments, comments created separately aren't connected with posts. My code is [here](https://github.com/CodeByLine/assess_new) and this is following the [Mozilla Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/django_assessment_blog):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commenter = models.ForeignKey('Commenter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_username = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    commenter = models.ForeignKey('Commenter', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)

class Commenter(models.Model):
    commenter_username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Does Django display any kind of error?

Comment: No error, except a comment should be connected to a post; a post may have one or more comments--or none. When I created a comment not linked to a post, I realized something wasn't right, but had a hard time fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried using `ManyToMany`, `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne` relationships? Instead of `ForeignKey`

Comment: With help from a few Redditers, the connection problem was solved--turned out I got the 'post' and 'comment' relationship backward: 'post' should be a foreign-key item in 'comment', not the other way around.